# VueJS prop behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So I have a book component in Vuejs that gets given a "book" prop which is an object with a title, color, chapters etc. Here is the code. The template works fine, and is able to create chapters. What I am trying to do is set the nav color on mount.

```
Vue.component('book', {
    props: ['book'],
    template: `
        <section class="book">
            <h1 :id="book.title"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> {{ book.title }} {{ book.description }}</h1>
            <chapter v-for="chapter in book.chapter" :chapter="chapter"></chapter>
        </section>
    `,
    mounted: function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.book);
        document.getElementById("nav").style.backgroundColor = '#' + this.book.color;
    }
});
```

In the mounted function, `console.log(this)` shows that the component correctly has the prop with an observer and all the attributes however when printing `this.book` only the observer shows up, which is why `this.book.color` doesn't work. Any reason for this inconsistency? Why isn't the book object in the component the same as `this.book`?

Comment: How do you view the data in the console? Usually the data is evaluated when you view it, not when you log it. Also, why not simply add the color in a `CSS` class from the start or like this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1

Comment: The backgroundColor is for the nav bar which is just a regular html element.

Comment: Try doing that in color change in `this.$nextTick()`.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. Your comment about evaluation on view got me on the right track. The book prop is initially empty and gets populated via ajax meaning I need to change the color on beforeUpdate instead of mounted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was that the book prop is populated via ajax, and the mounted function is then called when the component mounts, not when the actual data is loaded. The solution is to use beforeUpdate and set the color when the data changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `props` this way:

```
book: {
  type: Object,
  default: () => {}
}
```

Comment: It didn't quite solve the problem but it got me on the right track. The issue was that data was being fetched via ajax and I should have been changing the color on beforeUpdate instead of on mounted. I noticed it because the data was initially an array which failed the check, but didn't fail after fetching the ajax. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the book component is installed, the book data has been successfully obtained by the host element, so you can use the book, so:

```
<book v-if="!!book" :book="book"></book>
```